# How to center Dialog title in Material UI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

How can I center the `DialogTitle` (Material UI)? My code:

```
<Dialog
   open={this.state.open}
   titleStyle = {styles.Dialog}
   title='Title centered please!'
   actions={standardActions}
   onRequestClose={this.handleRequestClose}
>

  Dialog boby...
</Dialog>
```

[title with text "Ingreso de Procedimientos" centered please](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dW0uQ.png)

Comment: So what did you try to center it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This works for me:

```
<Dialog
   titleStyle={{textAlign: "center"}}
   ... />
```

Answer (score 3):

u can just simply use the dialog title component and add typography component in there

```
<DialogTitle>
  <Typography variant="h3" align="center">Centered Title</Typography>
</DialogTitle>
```

hope this help :))

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the shortest way in **MUI v5**. It is possible because `DialogTitle` returns a [styled `Typography`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/e75a347f7dfb0209e53a8997ff53a4fde53f8635/packages/mui-material/src/DialogTitle/DialogTitle.js#L21) which leverages [system properties](https://mui.com/components/typography/#system-props).

```
<DialogTitle textAlign="center">
```

### Live Demo

[image: Codesandbox Demo]

Answer (score 0):

None of the solutions work anymore. Try the following

```
 <DialogTitle>
    <label className={"h4 custom-flex-justify-center"}>Add New </label>
</DialogTitle>
```

and define **custom-flex-justify-center** class as follows

```
.custom-flex-justify-center {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

This works in Material UI 5 too

Answer (score 0):

Directly adding `Typography` props to the `<DialogTitle>` didn't work in my case.

I did however find in [the documentation](https://mui.com/material-ui/api/dialog-title/#props) that `<DialogTitle>` accepts a sx prop. Thus you can inline add styles as follows

```
<DialogTitle sx={{ textAlign:"center" }}>
```